# How to find a countable basis for $(\mathbb{R},|.|)$?

Tags: general-topology

I want to find a topological basis for $(\mathbb{R},|.|)$ which is countable ,

I know that $\{]x-r,x+r[,x\in\mathbb{R},r>0\}$ is a basis but it is not countable .

How to do?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use rationals instead of reals.

---

EDIT: Let $\mathcal{T}$ be the topology generated by $\{(q - p, q + p) : q, p \in \mathbb{Q}\}.$  Fix $x,r \in \mathbb{R}$ with $r > 0$.  Let $q_n$ be a sequence of rationals in $(x -r, x+r)$ converging to $x$.  Find a rational number $p_n$ so that $(q_n - p_n, q_n + p_n) \subset (x - r, x+ r)$ and $\min\{| (x - r) -  (q_n - p_n)|, |(x+r) - (q_n + p_n)|\} < 1/n.$

Then $(x - r, x+r) = \bigcup_n (q_n - p_n,q_n + p_n)$, implying $(x -r, x+ r) \in \mathcal{T}$.

Comment: i must take this $\{]q-r,q+r[, q\in\mathbb{Q}, r>0\}$?

Comment: That is still not countable. Try proving that $\{(q_1-q_2, q_1+q_2) : q_1, q_2\in\mathbb{Q}, q_2 > 0\}$ is a basis for the topology on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: to prove that $\{]q-p, q+p[, q_1,p\in\mathbb{Q}\}$ is a basis  what i must prove ? that $]q-p,q+p[\subset]x-r,x+r[$ ?

Comment: Please help me how to prove that $\{]q-p,q+p[\}$ is a basis ?

Comment: Since you know $(x - r, x + r), x \in \mathbb{R}, r > 0$ is a basis, it is sufficient to show that each such interval is in the topology generated by the $(q - p, q + p)$.

Comment: Like this it is more complicated, i know that $\{]x-r,x+r[\}$ is a basis because it is under all open intervals , how to do know  to go from real numbers to rational numbers ?

Comment: @Vrouvrou, You should use the fact that the rationals are dense in the real numbers.  Give this an honest shot, as it's a common argument in topology. If you can't figure out, I'll write the details later today.

Comment: @MarcusM i still don't understand how to do

Comment: @Vrouvrou, Okay, I added the details.

Comment: How we find $p_n$ ?